# .xap file is not showing in the sd card

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, installation, xap

I have developed one windows phone 8 application. I have tested the app in simulator and it is working fine. Now I have decided to test the app in my windows phone(Nokia Lumia 520).

**As you already know for testing the app, we need XAP file. So I have build the app in visual studio 2012 by right click on the project and select build option.Then XAP file is generated in the BIN folder of the application.**

**Now I have copied the XAP file to the SD Card 's root folder on my windows phone. After that I have restarted my windows phone. 
Now I click on the Start and then Store in my phone. Now it has to show SD Card option.
But I didn't get this option.**

**So to check this again, I have downloaded the application(XAP file) from windows store.Now I have copied the XAP file to the SD Card 's root folder on my windows phone. After that I have restarted my windows phone. Now I click on the Start and then Store in my phone.
Now the SD Card option is visible. But there is only one XAP file (which I downloaded from the store) is visible and the one which I have developed is not visible.**

I don't know what is the problem in my XAP file.
Please provide the solution as early as possible.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to follow the proper procedures for deploying a windows phone 8 app to a device. Connect your phone to your PC, In Visual studio 2012, select the deploy to device option and build the project. If you have a developer unlocked device, this will install the app on your phone.

[Deploying an app in visual studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402565%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_vs)

[Deploying an app using the application deployment tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402565%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_tool)

Comment: Hi FunksMaName, Thanks for your reply. My device is not developer unlocked. I'm getting the install option for downloaded application and not for the one which I have developed. Please check the below link. http://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/how-to/wp8/apps/how-do-i-install-apps-from-an-sd-card

Comment: AFAIK, you can't deploy an un-signed app to a phone without dev unlocking the phone. Apps that are available through the Store, beta apps or live apps are signed (I think using MS PlayReady DRM), hence they can be downloaded and side-loaded to a phone. When it is not signed, you cannot install it to a device without a dev unlock. There are currently two types of DEV unlock, See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769508%28v=vs.105%29.aspx If you do not have a dev account, you can still dev unlock your phone for free, you will be limited to one device and 2 apps.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot deploy a XAP file from your SD card on your phone but there are several other ways to do that:

- If you have a developer unlocked phone (that you should have as developer) you can connect the phone to your PC and directly deploy the XAP file to it via Visual Studio (select `Device` instead of `Emulator` as deploy target)
- Otherwise you can use the "Application Deployment" tool that comes with the Windows Phone SDK
- Third you can upload it as a Beta Version to the Windows Phone Store which his is very uncommon way because if you have Windows Phone Store Account you can also unlock your phone...

Comment: Hi Robin, Thanks for your reply.I don't have developer unlocked device. But also, as per the below link procedure I did and I'm able to install the app which I have downloaded from store. But I'm unable to install the app(which i have developed). http://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/how-to/wp8/apps/how-do-i-install-apps-from-an-sd-card